# Plotting JSON locations using Google Road API with Javascript Promise chaining

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, google-maps, data-visualization

I wrote this code for an personal application, just to help me visualize some data related to driving. I have one JSON on my machine, this JSON contains a set of locations (lat, lngs) and every location has a category (integer number).

After I fetch this file I want to use [Google's Road API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap), to snap the points on the road. Unfortunately it only allows 100 points per request. And depending on the "track" I can have usually 400+ points.

At this point, this application is only maintained by me. But I used this as an excuse to re-learn Javascript (including the new stuff only new browsers have).

I used Promises and I was used to the callback hell of before and after reading so much good stuff about Promises I got really frustrated seeing this huge chaining I made.

It's working, can't complain about that. 
But, looks messy.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(evt){
    'use strict';

    const apiKey = '-----------';

    let rawMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('rawMap'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 10
    });

    let snappedMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('snappedMap'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 10
    });

    const colors = [
        '#FF0000',
        '#00FF00',
        '#0000FF',
        '#FFFF00',
        '#00FFFF',
        '#FF00FF',
        '#000000',
    ];

    fetch('output.json').then(response => response.json()).then(function(points){
        for (let i = 0 ; i < points.length - 1 ; ++i) {
            let path = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [points[i], points[i+1]],
                strokeColor: colors[points[i]['cat']],
                strokeWeight: 5
            });

            path.setMap(rawMap);
        }

        let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        points.forEach(point => bounds.extend(point));
        rawMap.fitBounds(bounds)
        snappedMap.fitBounds(bounds);

        let requests = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < points.length ; i += 100) {
            let params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('interpolate', 'true');
            params.append('key', apiKey)
            params.append('path', points.slice(i, i + 100).map(point => `${point['lat']},${point['lng']}`).join('|'));

            requests.push(fetch(`https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?${params}`));
        }

        return Promise.all(requests)
                        .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json())))
                        .then(function(jsons){
                            for (let i = 0, lastIndex = -1; i < jsons.length ; ++i) {
                                let snappedPoints = jsons[i].snappedPoints;

                                for (let snappedPoint of snappedPoints) {
                                    if ('originalIndex' in snappedPoint) {
                                        lastIndex = i * 100 + snappedPoint.originalIndex;
                                    }

                                    snappedPoint['cat'] = points[lastIndex]['cat'];
                                }
                            }

                            return jsons;
                        });
    }).then(function(jsons) {
        return jsons.reduce((ret, json) => ret.concat(json.snappedPoints), [])
    }).then(function(snappedPoints){
        for (let i = 0; i < snappedPoints.length - 1; i++) {
            let path = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                    {
                        lat: snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
                        lng: snappedPoints[i].location.longitude
                    },
                    {
                        lat: snappedPoints[i+1].location.latitude,
                        lng: snappedPoints[i+1].location.longitude
                    }
                ],
                strokeWeight:5,
                strokeColor: colors[snappedPoints[i]['cat']]
            });

            path.setMap(snappedMap);
        }
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Divide processing in simple functions, then chain them in linear fashion.
- Use literal `.property` or `['property']` consistently, don't mix them as it's the same in JS
- Concatenate arrays in one operation via `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays)` instead of `reduce` that creates intermediate arrays (it's slow and memory-hogging).  However, if the number of elements may exceed 32k (the max number of arguments in some browsers) it's safer to `concat` in chunks of 10k by using a loop and `.slice`.

```
// your init part
```

```
let points;
```

```
const getJSON = (response) => response.json();
```

```
const drawPoints = (json) => {
    // will be used later for snapping to roads
    points = json;

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; ++i) {
        let path = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [points[i], points[i + 1]],
            strokeColor: colors[points[i].cat],
            strokeWeight: 5
        });
        path.setMap(rawMap);
    }

    // fit map bounds to the points
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    points.forEach(point => bounds.extend(point));
    rawMap.fitBounds(bounds);
    snappedMap.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

```
const requestSnapToRoads = () => {
    let requests = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i += 100) {
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('interpolate', 'true');
        params.append('key', apiKey)
        params.append('path', points
            .slice(i, i + 100)
            .map(point => `${point.lat},${point.lng}`)
            .join('|'));
        requests.push(fetch(`https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?${params}`));
    }
    return Promise.all(requests).then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(getJSON)));
};
```

```
const applySnapToRoads = (jsons) => {
    let lastIndex = -1;
    let allSnappedPoints = jsons.map((json, i) => {
        for (let snappedPoint of json.snappedPoints) {
            if ('originalIndex' in snappedPoint) {
                lastIndex = i * 100 + snappedPoint.originalIndex;
            }
            snappedPoint.cat = points[lastIndex].cat;
        }
        return json.snappedPoints;
    });
    return [].concat.apply([], allSnappedPoints);
};
```

```
const drawSnappedPoints = (snappedPoints) => {
    const getPointAt = (index) => ({
        lat: snappedPoints[index].location.latitude,
        lng: snappedPoints[index].location.longitude
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < snappedPoints.length - 1; i++) {
        let path = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [getPointAt(i), getPointAt(i + 1)],
            strokeWeight: 5,
            strokeColor: colors[snappedPoints[i].cat]
        });
        path.setMap(snappedMap);
    }
};
```

> // chain them!

```
fetch('output.json')
    .then(getJSON)
    .then(drawPoints)
    .then(requestSnapToRoads)
    .then(applySnapToRoads)
    .then(drawSnappedPoints)
    .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment. But without further ado: WOW! This was like really impressive, I really liked the result and been studying it a lot.
Couple of questions though, just to understand the rationale and standards, 1) why creating functions with the arrow functions? just to preserve the ```this``` object? 2) Why one function per step even though it would never (until now) be used again, for readability? 3) I thought one of the plus of Promises was the fact it doesn't need to declare variables out from its scope, so that ```let points;``` would never exist or am I ***really*** wrong?

Comment: 1. Personally, I'd use local `function` declarations as I'm used to ES5 but here arrow functions are used for syntax consistency only 2. When a function does just one simple task it's much easier to understand for anyone (this is explained better in many coding guides) 3. Regarding `let points`, I've used the simplest solution (you use out-of-scope variables anyway). I could have transferred the variable via Promise chain for better encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use promises only where it's necessary, a couple of the
transformations here can just be put into a regular variable without
problems, the `.json()` calls for example.

- Extract duplicate code like the map creation since all the parameters
  are the same except for the element ID.
- Extract semantically useful code into functions.
- Be consistent with the semicolons.
- Maybe also use functional mapping to iterate over arrays to get of the
  manual `for`-loops.
- The first nested `return Promise.all(requests).then(...)` should
  probably be put one layer up so it flows better, that is,
  `... return Promise.all(requests); }).then(function(responses){...})`.

Otherwise yeah, looks good.